# Spring Boot OAuth2 implicit flow + form login and Request method 'POST' not supported error

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

In my Spring Boot application I'm trying to configure OAuth2 implicit flow. For this purpose I'm trying to configure custom login form.

This is my config:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private SocialAuthenticationSuccessHandler socialAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private DBUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Value("${social.postLogin.url}")
    private String postLoginUrl;

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        // Spring Security ignores request to static resources such as CSS or JS
        // files.
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/static/**");
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        // @formatter:off
        http.addFilterBefore(new CorsFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class);

        // Set a custom successHandler on the SocialAuthenticationFilter
        final SpringSocialConfigurer socialConfigurer = new SpringSocialConfigurer();
        socialConfigurer.addObjectPostProcessor(new ObjectPostProcessor<SocialAuthenticationFilter>() {
            @Override
            public <O extends SocialAuthenticationFilter> O postProcess(O socialAuthenticationFilter) {
                socialAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(socialAuthenticationSuccessHandler);
                socialAuthenticationFilter.setPostLoginUrl(postLoginUrl);
                return socialAuthenticationFilter;
            }
        });

        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()

            .antMatchers("/oauth/authorize").authenticated()
            //Anyone can access the urls
            .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/actuator/health").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/actuator/**").hasAuthority("PERMISSION_READ_ACTUATOR_DATA")
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .permitAll()
        //Adds the SocialAuthenticationFilter to Spring Security's filter chain.
        .and()
            // apply the configuration from the socialConfigurer (adds the SocialAuthenticationFilter)
            .apply(socialConfigurer);
        // @formatter:on
    }

    /**
     * Configures the authentication manager bean which processes authentication
     * requests.
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

}

@Configuration
public class OAuth2ServerConfig {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "restservice";

    @Autowired
    private DBUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter() {

            @Override
            public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken accessToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
                DBUserDetails user = (DBUserDetails) authentication.getUserAuthentication().getPrincipal();
                final Map<String, Object> additionalInfo = new HashMap<>();
                additionalInfo.put("user_id", user.getUser().getId());
                ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) accessToken).setAdditionalInformation(additionalInfo);
                OAuth2AccessToken enhancedToken = super.enhance(accessToken, authentication);
                return enhancedToken;
            }

        };

        converter.setSigningKey("123");

        DefaultAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter = new DefaultAccessTokenConverter();
        DefaultUserAuthenticationConverter userTokenConverter = new DefaultUserAuthenticationConverter();
        userTokenConverter.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        accessTokenConverter.setUserTokenConverter(userTokenConverter);

        converter.setAccessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter);

        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Autowired
        private TokenStore tokenStore;

        @Autowired
        private TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            endpoints
                .tokenStore(tokenStore)
                .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancer)
                .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager);
            // @formatter:on
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            clients
                .inMemory()
                    .withClient("clientapp")
                        .authorizedGrantTypes("password","refresh_token")
                        //.authorizedGrantTypes("implicit")
                        .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT")
                        .scopes("read", "write")
                        .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID)
                        .secret("123456")
                    .and()
                    .withClient("clientapp1")
                        .authorizedGrantTypes("implicit")
                        .scopes("read", "write")
                        .autoApprove(true);
            // @formatter:on
        }

    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private ResourceServerTokenServices tokenService;

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
            // @formatter:off
            resources           
                .resourceId(RESOURCE_ID)
                .tokenServices(tokenService);
            // @formatter:on
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/profile/*").authenticated()
                    .and().csrf()
                    .disable().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS);
            // @formatter:on
        }

    }

}
```

login.html page Thymeleaf template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
    <head>
        <title>Spring Security Example </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div th:if="${param.error}">
            Invalid username and password.
        </div>
        <div th:if="${param.logout}">
            You have been logged out.
        </div>
        <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
            <div><label> User Name : <input type="text" name="username"/> </label></div>
            <div><label> Password: <input type="password" name="password"/> </label></div>
            <div><input type="submit" value="Sign In"/></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Maven artifact versions:**

```
<spring.boot.version>1.4.0.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
<spring-security-core.version>4.1.3.RELEASE</spring-security-core.version>
<spring-security-oauth2.version>2.0.11.RELEASE</spring-security-oauth2.version>
```

Right now, when I'm trying to access following url:

```
http://localhost:8080/oauth/authorize?response_type=implicit&client_id=clientapp1
```

I'm successfully redirected to my login page at `http://localhost:8080/login` but when I enter username/password and press "Sign in" button I'm getting following error:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Sat Sep 24 21:19:44 EEST 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'POST' not supported
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix this issue ?

**UPDATED**

In debug I can see the following output:

```
DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing POST request for [/login]
2016-09-25 10:04:43 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping -
                Looking up handler method for path /login
2016-09-25 10:04:43 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping -
                Did not find handler method for [/login]
2016-09-25 10:04:43 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping -
                Mapping [/login] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController@c85e70] and 1 interceptor
2016-09-25 10:04:43 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver -
                Resolving exception from handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController@c85e70]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported
2016-09-25 10:04:43 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver -
                Resolving exception from handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController@c85e70]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported
2016-09-25 10:04:43 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound -
                Request method 'POST' not supported
2016-09-25 10:04:43 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.h.writers.HstsHeaderWriter -
                Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@16580a4
2016-09-25 10:04:43 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet -
                Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2016-09-25 10:04:43 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet -
                Successfully completed request
```

Also, there is another question about this issue with no answer provided [usernamepasswordauthenticationfilter not getting invoked in spring security with oauth2 and formlogin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34465798/usernamepasswordauthenticationfilter-not-getting-invoked-in-spring-security-with)

Comment: remove `method="post"` from jsp. and also you have to add a request handler for `/error` request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my issue with a wrong configuration of ResourceServer.

With a following configuration everything is working fine:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private ResourceServerTokenServices tokenService;

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        // @formatter:off
        resources           
            .resourceId(RESOURCE_ID)
            .tokenServices(tokenService);
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http                
            .antMatcher("/api/**" )
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS);
        // @formatter:on
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

I had this same problem today, your answer didn't help me, but I found a solution to my problem.

Hopefully this helps someone else in the same position.

The problem for my app is that I'm using Basic Auth to cover most of my web application's protected resources, but I'm using OAuth2 in order to protect a public API that I'm allowing people to connect to.

So this caused my application to have two separate `public void configure(HttpSecurity http)` methods in two separate configuration files.

The solution was to add an `Order` annotation to the configuration classes.

So my main configuration class that used Basic Auth had `Order(1)` assigned to it, and the `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` had an `Order(2)` annotation assigned to it.

For example:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(1)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
  /// ... my normal configuration information
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
    // my basic auth config
  }
}

@Configuration
@Order(2)
public class OAuth2ServerConfig
{
  @Configuration
  @EnableResourceServer
  @Order(3)
  protected static class Oauth2ServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter
  {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
      http.authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/oauth/**").permitAll()
      .antMatchers("/api/v1/**").access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')");
    }
  }


  @Configuration
  @EnableAuthorizationServer
  protected static class AuthorizationServer extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter
  {
    // authorization server settings
  }
}
```

Comment: Love you so much @Trevor xD